# Unix Java path variables is being reset

Tags: java, unix

I have a machine running RHEL 6. Currently JDK 7 is installed. For ElasticSearch I need to move to JDK 8. SO i copied the JDK 1.8 to /opt/. THen ran the below steps.

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /opt/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/java 100 
update-alternatives --config java
```

Did the same thing for Javac as well.
Then did the below changes to Environment variables

```
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_45/
export PATH=/opt/jdk1.8.0_45/bin:...
```

In setting path, i copied the existing path, removed the jdk7 entries and added the entire path again.

After this when i ran java -version i got 8. But on restarting the shell, it reverted back to 1.7!!!

So i checked internet and found that i need to update the /etc/profile file 
So added below two entries..

```
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_66/
export PATH=/opt/jdk1.8.0_66/bin:$PATH
```

But even afer this, the JDK 1.7 is being append to teh Path variable.

Any pointers on how i can move to JDK 1.8

Comment: What does `alternatives --display java` say?

Comment: I got it working. There was a script file inside /etc/profiles.d/. It was named as jdk.sh. There the JAVA_HOME and PATH was being set. I changed this to the jdk1.8 and the issue was solved. Thanks.
i got a comment from Stackoverflow about the way to set the Path using script inside profile.d folder. So searched there and found the script. Took me 2 hours to figure this out...

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. There was a script file inside /etc/profiles.d/. It was named as jdk.sh. There the JAVA_HOME and PATH was being set. I changed this to the jdk1.8 and the issue was solved. Thanks. i got a comment from Stackoverflow about the way to set the Path using script inside profile.d folder. So searched there and found the script. Took me 2 hours to figure this out... – Shabin Hashim